# Print filename in extension

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a simple extension for `UIView` with some helpers methods. For debug purposes I want to print filename, line, etc for these methods, so I can easily find exactly which view and where I can find this view, when something went wrong. My question, is there a way to print these info using `#file` and `#line` without passing it as default param to method:

```
//What I can do
func pinToSuperview(file: String = #file) { print(file) }

//What I want. Can I somehow achieve these?
func pinToSuperview() { print(#file) }
```

I found a way of using `debugPrint()` but these will just print type and address, instead of filename, line etc.

Comment: If you want file name/line number of the *caller*  then the default parameter value is the only way.

Comment: `#file` and `#line` are going to be the file and line in which they appear, so you have to pass them to get the information for the line and file where they are called.  By making them default values at the end, you don't actually have to specify them when `pinToSuperview` is called, so the overhead is just the signature of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to log file name and line number of the *caller* of that method, this is the only way. Compare [Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html) (emphasis added)

> When used as the **default value of a function** or method parameter, the special literal’s value is determined when the default value expression is **evaluated at the call site.**

In your case:

```
// Function defined in file "A.swift"
func pinToSuperview(file: String = #file) { print(file) }

// Function called in file "B.swift"
pinToSuperview()
```

would print "B.swift". On the other hand, `#file` inside the function body expands to the file name where the function is defined, so

```
// Function defined in file "A.swift"
func pinToSuperview() { print(#file) }

// Function called in file "B.swift"
pinToSuperview()
```

would print "A.swift".